# Apache ECharts: "time" Axis labels are overlapping when using DataZoom

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I am using Apache ECharts to create a line chart with an Y Axis of type "value" and an X Axis of type "time". I am also implementing dataZoom on the X Axis, which is working correctly. The problem is that when I move the dataZoom a bit, this happens:

[image]

My data consist of series with actual `Date` objects for the X axis, like:

[image]

Then, I have the following config for the X Axis. As you can see, I have specified a formatter in the Axis to convert dates to strings, which also works correctly.

[image]

Finally, my DataZoom config is just:

```
{ dataZoom: [{}] }
```

I am setting the same config as other time charts in ECharts official examples, but I am still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Show you code with jsfiddle or another tool. By the provided image impossible to guess.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
xAxis: {
      axisLabel: {
        hideOverlap: true,
      }
}
```

This should solve the overlapping issue.