# Can I disable first of month/year labels for a xAxis of type 'time' to get even intervals?

Tags: echarts

When I have a chart over several months, the interval is set to include the first of the month making intervals uneven and causing labels to overlap. Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to disable this?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPCTk.png)

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-pieces&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5JALZW0A0JAvm-uTvkaqTKUasWgDcAhgBsArsy6xOJPFQBOEKoVgBtEugGCh1OlIjR5e0nnIMARsCl1oMC4dinzAZQpSRBtwDGDsCqdADEAKwALADsAAwAwgBsrJaCAO4QACZgABZEEWmKCoJZEmASRLpu6Nq0AExxAIwAnAC0cQAcbU0xrLCNcQC6JYZ1ja09cVP9gyNFtQ3N7U3TTU39EUnDo4Ljy1M99f0xETsLOkuTqz0AzJud5zWXEytrUbNn88_712sR_VucSeNV-bx6KRYsCiX12pDBh16gOB31BVxWTR6AKhq2GRSGlnYJAJ7AA3EA) is an example based off one of echarts examples.

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      lineStyle: {
        color: '#5470C6',
        width: 5
      },
      data: [
        ['2019-08-17', 200],
        ['2019-10-10', 200],
        ['2019-10-11', 560],
        ['2019-10-12', 750],
        ['2019-10-13', 580],
        ['2019-10-14', 250],
        ['2019-10-15', 300],
        ['2019-10-16', 450],
        ['2019-10-17', 300],
        ['2019-11-15', 100]
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: This question has already been answered several times: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477681/echarts-5-axis-label-overlap ,  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274257/apache-echarts-time-axis-labels-are-overlapping-when-using-datazoom

Comment: My problem is less about the overlap, and more about the uneven intervals. Sure, I can hide the overlapping label, but then it just has kind of random intervals and still looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want even intervals, you can instruct echarts to treat the dates as discrete values by changing the configuration of the axis:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
}
```